# Docusign - Signers are not getting email

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

Signers are not getting email even though I've unchecked the Signing Setting "Suppress emails to embedded signers" to allow for emails to be sent to signers who are set as embedded. Can you guys please help me?

[image]

Comment: can you share the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

This setting (**Suppress emails to embedded signers**) is not going to impact integrations using the eSignature API when they use the embedded signing flow.
Meaning, that the initial email message is not sent when you specify **clientUserId** for a non-null/empty value.

To clarify, the email sent by DocuSign that is used to start the signing process, that is the email I'm mean, not subsequent emails that may give you additional information about the envelope.